# How to install large chunk of libraries in python using pip by ignoring versions of libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

python libraries that I want to install using pip by ignoring version errors.

[image: python libraries that I want to install using pip by ignoring version errors.]

Comment: The image link you have provided in the description contains only texts. So it would be better if you include the text in that image directly in the description. And if you need to use an image for clarification, then insert that image directly rather than referring it.

Comment: You can try of keeping all names in requirements.txt file and 'pip install requirements.txt' will work for yoU/

Answer (score 0):

Open your requirements file in your favorite text editor and use this `([0-9A-Za-z-]+)(\=\=[0-9.]+)` **regular expression** in the find and replace box with the regular expression in the find field and either `$1` or `\1` in the replace field and then press replace all or whatever your text editor and save provides for example

[image]

At the end of it all, you will have only the package names without their version numbers on each line.
After that, you can run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Using unix tools `cat` for sending the file to stdout and `sed` to cut from `==` to the end of line; xargs to apply the command to every line read from stdin:

```
cat req | sed 's/==.\+$//' | xargs pip install
```